# How to resize a logo proportionaly to a figure?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I want to add a logo in my figure. So im using this code:

```
for code, data in normals.groupby('CODE'):
    
    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, sharex=False, sharey=False,figsize=(20, 15))
    data.plot('MONTH',["TMAX"], alpha=0.5, color='red', marker='P', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax1)

    data.plot('MONTH',["TMIN"], alpha=0.5,color='blue',marker='D', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax2)

    data.plot('MONTH',["PP"],kind='bar',color='green', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax3)

    table=ax4.table(cellText=data[['TMAX','TMIN','PP']].T.values,colLabels=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August",
                         "September","October","November","December"],
              rowLabels=data[['TMAX','TMIN','PP']].columns,rowColours =["blue"] * 3,  
        colColours =["blue"] * 12,loc="center",bbox = [0.0, -0.5, 1, 1])
    
    logo = plt.imread('path/to/image/logo.jpg')

    plt.figimage(logo,origin='upper')
```

But the issue is that i don't know how to resize the logo proportionaly to the figure `fig`. Also i have a loop so maybe is harder to do.

Would you mind to help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like:

```py
# adjust the numbers below to taste:

ax_logo = fig.add_axes([0.01, 0.01, 0.08, 0.08])
ax_logo.imshow(logo)
ax_logo.axis('off')
```